# Select Clients between two SETS of dates, rather than just two dates

Tags: sql, between

I have the following code:

```
select ifnull(c.clientid,0) as ClientID, c.surname as Surname, c.addr1 as Address1, c.postcode as Postcode
from cust c
where (c.tour_date between '2019-06-10' and '2019-06-18')
and (c.tour_date between '2019-07-15' and '2019-07-23')
group by ClientID, Surname, Address1, Postcode
order by ClientID asc
```

And it's not working - what I'm trying to do is select dates between two sets of dates. Traditionally we would just select 2019-06-10 and 2019-07-23 but there's lots of clients we include that shouldn't be included.

Nevermind, I changed the `and` to `or` and it's working, silly me!

EDIT2: Ah, actually, when I use `or` I get 2,005 clients, but when I do two separate extracts I come up with  2,029 clients. Any ideas?

Comment: You can delete this question!

Comment: `when I do "or" I get 2,005 clients, but when I do two separate extracts I come up with 2,029 clients.. Any ideas?` : Because there must be some rows which satisfy both date conditions. So when extracting separately you get those rows and when using `or` condition it only outputs once for any one of the condition only

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @jarlh . . . You can vote to close as a typographical error.

Comment: I always thought it was beneficial to leave solved queries open for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You have more clients on separate queries because some have records between both date ranges. Your group by clause removes the duplicates.